# Unable to use composer vendor as codeigniter library

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to use this (*https://github.com/Achse/geth-jsonrpc-php-client*) library using composer and codeigniter. But I am getting below error:

```
Type: Error

Message: Class 'GuzzleClient' not found

Filename: /var/www/html/test/application/libraries/Ethereum.php

Line Number: 7
```

And below is my library code:

```
<?php

class Ethereum
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $httpClient = new GuzzleClient(new GuzzleClientFactory(), 'localhost', 8545);
        $client     = new Client($httpClient);

        return $client;
    }

}
```

Composer is wel loaded as other dependancies are working fine. Not able to find out the issue. plz help

Comment: Have you included [GuzzleClient](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle) in your project ?

Comment: The error message looks correct to me. The `GuzzleClient` class you want to use has a different name (mind the namespace here), check out the original class for its namespace. /edit: original class is defined here: https://github.com/Achse/geth-jsonrpc-php-client/blob/master/src/JsonRpc/GuzzleClient.php

Comment: And just a tip: Prevent the use of `new` inside `__construct()`  methods.

Comment: @hakre Why shouldn't you allocate objects in __construct()?

Comment: @VojtechKane: I'm glad you ask. If an object depends on other objects it should get them injected. If the `new` keyword is used inside the constructor method, it shows that these are not injected.

Comment: Constructors do not return a value they serve only to instantiate the class. That said, there isn't any reason you cannot use `new` in the constructor.

Comment: @DFriend: I didn't say you cannot use `new`. You for sure can, it even works for what it has been made for. I just commented that you shouldn't make use of `new` in a constructor method. That is a design related, not what the syntax allows. Just for clarification and differentiation.

Comment: I said, there is no reason `new` should not be used in a constructor method. You have twice said is should not be used in a constructor and you are incorrect. It is done frequently in many different frameworks. In the context of CodeIgniter anytime you use `$this->load->library('some_library')` a `new` statement is eventually executed - assuming the library can be found. All that said, it would be wise to use `try/catch` blocks with any such `new` calls.

Comment: As now I understand what @hakre ment, I agree with him. Most of the `new`s shoud be avoided with dependency injection. It makes the code clearer and faster (you can easily reuse dependencies). Of course not all classes should be obtained using DI (data storage classes like coordinates, for example), but that is not the case of `GuzzleClient`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Composer you typically have to include an `autoload.php` file. You also need to used namespaces for the Composer dependencies.

Usually the `vendor` directory is on the same level as `application` so it's handy to define a constant to point to the vendor directory.

```
define('VENDOR', substr(FCPATH, 0, strpos(APPPATH, 'application/')) . "vendor/");
```

Your library maybe needs to look more like this.

```
<?php
require VENDOR . 'autoload.php';

//I'm not certain this is the correct namespace but hopefully you get the idea
use Achse\GethJsonRpcPhpClient; 

class Ethereum
{
    protected $httpClient;
    protected $client;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->httpClient = new GuzzleClient(new GuzzleClientFactory(), 'localhost', 8545);
        $this->client     = new Client($httpClient);
    }

    //example using the class property $client
    public getResult()
    {
        return $this->client->callMethod('eth_getBalance', ['0xf99ce9c17d0b4f5dfcf663b16c95b96fd47fc8ba', 'latest']);
    }
}
```

Comment: not working still.. unable to find what may be the error ! did everything as said

Comment: Probably I have the wrong namespace. Try to find other online examples of using the library and checkout their namespace value. Also I am making an assumption about where your `vendor` folder is located.

Comment: This (https://github.com/Achse/geth-jsonrpc-php-client/blob/master/src/JsonRpc/GuzzleClient.php) should be the namespace. I tried but still same error.

Comment: Best is to find out the fully qualified classname first for each of these classes. You can even use the full names. The error messages are then most often more saying.

Comment: That's the location of the files, not the namespace. The autoloader creates a connection between namespaces and file locations.